# How do I add a counter to a javascript text area that counts like Twitter but instead of down it goes up to a maximum of 150 characters

Tags: javascript, character, countdown, max

I know little about javascript and implementing it but I found this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
```

and then this piece to implement it:

```
<form name="myform">
<textarea name="limitedtextarea" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,100);">
</textarea><br>
<font size="1">(Maximum characters: 100)<br>
You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="100"> character left.</font>
</form>
```

How do I make it instead of it counting down but to count up to 150 characters?

Comment: Why not try to understand what the code is doing first? Then you'll be able to make it go up.

Comment: I agree with elclanrs. If you need to ask questions on simple issues such as these, it will result in a far slower development time. If you're only interested in getting by, you can use the internet as a learning resource. If you often use Javascript in your job, however, I'd recommend a more advanced and comprehensive book, such as Javascript: The Definitive Guide. I've provided you with the code this time, but I guarantee you it would have been far faster to simply edit the code yourself if you understood Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code you need:

Javascript portion:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        // notice I set the value of the count to the length of the field
        // rather than setting it to the max chars - the length of the field
        limitCount.value = limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML portion:

```
<!-- changed all occurrences of 100 to 150 to match your specified max characters -->
<form name="myform">
<textarea name="limitedtextarea" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,150);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,150);">
</textarea><br>
<font size="1">(Maximum characters: 150)<br>
<!-- here I changed "You have x characters left" to "You have used x characters." -->
You have used <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="0"> characters.</font>
</form>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/EcDBE/

I recommend trying to actually understand the changes I've made, rather than simply copying and pasting the provided code, however. To aid you in this, I put comments in the code to show what changes I made.